# How to condition appearance of a gutenberg block via wp_is_mobile

Tags: block-editor

Good morning everyone I'm looking for some suggestions to make a script / plugin that basically does this (in Gutenberg environment): condition the publishing of a block depending on the device via the wp_is_mobile function.

The most common use might be this: create two cover blocks, one for desktop and one for mobile.

There are dozens of plugins to achieve this, but all of them, via css display:none to one block or another depending on the user's device. This solution is not efficient as the hidden image is still loaded in the browser penalizing the user and slowing down the site (Pagespeed).

I found a paid plugin that generically talks about server-side mobile conditions but does 200 other things that I honestly don't care about.

Finally, I found another plugin that I am currently using Mobile Blocks
By PootlePress that does exactly that, only not using wp_is_mobile but regular expressions that intercept mobile devices user agents (but, unlike the WordPress feature, not tablets) and display the block built for them. The point is that it sometimes crashes and that is, it triggers the mobile version on desktop (especially on cached or highly optimized sites) and is not updated very often.

So I was thinking about how to create a hand-built, ready-to-use solution.
The first solution I came up with is to use a plugin like lazy blocks, ACF blocks, etc. and create a custom block with two images that are activated via php and wp_is_mobile function (one or the other). However, I still have to install additional plugins just for this simple (to say, but not to do) activity.
Another method would be to parse all blocks with parse_blocks(), and use wp_is_mobile to make a certain cover block appear rather than another. The point is that even this solution does not seem efficient to me.

And so I thought I would ask for advice from those here who know much more than me, some suggestions, alternative point of view!
Thank you!!!

Comment: `wp_is_mobile` won't help you if you use CDNs such as cloudfront, and it's generally not reliable to do it from the server side. The real solution to this is to use media queries in CSS and JS, this can never be done reliably server side

Comment: Do you really need separate markup for mobile vs. desktop, or can you achieve what you're looking for with CSS? Responsive styling can usually accommodate whatever layout changes you want and hide some content if it's really necessary, and it's not hard to swap out background images based on screen size.

Comment: I do not use CDN.
I want to separate markup. I know that I can achieve it with CSS, but, as I wrote, everything with display:none is loaded by the browser. Anyway I have to use two different images one for the desktop, one for mobile, also the paragraph over the images is different...